# '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'`

While running the following piece of code:

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

def retrieve_quotes_historical(stock_code):
    quotes = []
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/history?p=%s' % (stock_code, stock_code)
    r = requests.get(url)
    m = re.findall('"HistoricalPriceStore":{"prices":(.*?), "isPending"', r.text)
    if m:
        quotes = json.loads(m[0])
        quotes = quotes[::-1]
    return  [item for item in quotes if not 'type' in item]

quotes = retrieve_quotes_historical('INTC')
df = pd.DataFrame(quotes)

s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='s'))
df.date = s.dt.date
df = df.set_index('date')
```

This piece runs all smooth, but when I try to run this piece of code:

```
df['2017-07-07':'2017-07-10']
```

I get the TypeError.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add more context to the question? instead of just code

Answer (score 40):

The thing is you want to slice using Strings `'2017-07-07'` while your index is of type `datetime.date`. Your slices should be of this type too.

You can do this by defining your startdate and endate as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

startdate = pd.to_datetime("2017-7-7").date()
enddate = pd.to_datetime("2017-7-10").date()
df.loc[startdate:enddate]
```

startdate & enddate are now of type `datetime.date` and your slice will work:

```
            adjclose    close        high        low            open        volume
date
2017-07-07    33.205006    33.880001    34.119999    33.700001    33.700001    18304500
2017-07-10    32.979588    33.650002    33.740002    33.230000    33.250000    29918400
```

It is also possible to create datetime.date type without pandas:

```
import datetime

startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-07-07', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-07-10', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Comment: This is correct, useful, and helpful.  Thank you.  I can't help wondering why Pandas can't have a shorthand for dates so we can write them as strings and have them understood as dates or date times without so much additional verbiage.  Something like SAS's '23-01-05 5:00:00'dt, although you couldn't use single quotes for this.

Comment: I get why this makes sense, however this filtering by strings approach used to work for me although my index consisted of datetime objects. I don't really get why it stopped to work now.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798686/7262247), a few things to note:

- `pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='s')` already returns a `Series` so you do not need to wrap it.
- besides, **when parsing is successful** the `Series` returned by `pd.to_datetime` has `dtype` datetime64[ns] (timezone-naïve) or  datetime64[ns, tz] (timezone-aware). If parsing fails, it may still return a Series without error, of dtype `O` for "object" (at least in pandas 1.2.4), denoting falling back to Python's stdlib `datetime.datetime`.
- filtering using strings as in `df['2017-07-07':'2017-07-10']` only works when the `dtype` of the index is `datetime64[...]`, *not* when it is `O` (object

So with all of this, your example can be made to work by only changing the last lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(quotes)
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='s')   # no need to wrap in Series
assert str(s.dtype) == 'datetime64[ns]'   # VERY IMPORTANT!!!!
df.index = s
print(df['2020-08-01':'2020-08-10'])    # it now works!
```

It yields:

```
                           date       open  ...    volume   adjclose
date                                        ...
2020-08-03 13:30:00  1596461400  48.270000  ...  31767100  47.050617
2020-08-04 13:30:00  1596547800  48.599998  ...  29045800  47.859154
2020-08-05 13:30:00  1596634200  49.720001  ...  29438600  47.654583
2020-08-06 13:30:00  1596720600  48.790001  ...  23795500  47.634968
2020-08-07 13:30:00  1596807000  48.529999  ...  36765200  47.105358
2020-08-10 13:30:00  1597066200  48.200001  ...  37442600  48.272457
```

Also finally note that if your datetime format somehow contains the time offset, there seem to be a mandatory `utc=True` argument to add (in Pandas 1.2.4) to `pd.to_datetime`, otherwise the returned dtype will be 'O' even if parsing is successful. I hope that this will improve in the future, as it is not intuitive at all.

See [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) documentation for details.